# Apache Camel 2.17 RouteBuilder when file is empty route not working

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to route NULL or Empty messages to a local archive on system, and process files having content. Using Camel 2.17, Jboss Fuse servicemix bundle. I can't get it to work correctly. it has to be something I'm doing wrong. I've tried a few different things seen below ( all commented ).

Examples Tried:

```
    } else if (Boolean.parseBoolean(isCompressedOnly)) { //Only Zipped or Compressed
        // .when(simple("${file:length} == 0"))  
        // .when(simple("${header.CamelFileLength} == 0" )) 
        // .when(header("CamelFileLength").isEqualTo(0))
        // .when(body().isNull())
        // .when(header("CamelFileLength").isEqualTo(0))
        // .when(simple("${header.CamelFileLength} &lt; 10" ))
        // .when(simple("${header.CamelFileLength} &eq; 0" ))
        // .when(simple("${file:length} == null"))  

        ZipFileDataFormat zipFile = new ZipFileDataFormat();
        zipFile.setUsingIterator(true);

        from(fromStr)
        .routeId("Zipped.Only")
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Message received ${file:name} for Only Zipped or Compressed files from host " + host)
        .unmarshal(zipFile)
        .split(body(Iterator.class))
        .streaming()
        .convertBodyTo(String.class)
        .choice()
        .when(simple("${file:length} == null"))
        .wireTap("file" + errorArchive)
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO,"File Size: ${header.CamelFileLength}, File is Empty or Zero Length!")
        .endChoice()
        .otherwise()
            .wireTap("file:" + fileArchive)
            .split(body().tokenize("\n"), new FleetAggregationStrategy()).streaming()
            .process(new EndpointParametersProcessor(decoderName))
            .end()
            .to(toStr);
    } else {
```

The only statement that works kind of ( because all messages get routed to the null file endpoint, even if they have length/size/data/content )

```
.when(simple("${header.CamelFileLength} &lt; 10" ))
```

can you tell me what I am doing wrong? thank you!

Where can I find the methods associated with Header? e.g.
 .when(header("result").isEqualTo("A")
          .to(routeA)

I have tried not nesting the choice()'s but everything gets routed thru the first when().

```
        ZipFileDataFormat zipFile = new ZipFileDataFormat();
        zipFile.setUsingIterator(true);

        from(fromStr)
        .routeId("Zipped.Only")
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Message received ${file:name} for Only Zipped or Compressed files from host " + host)
        .unmarshal(zipFile)
        .split(body(Iterator.class))
        .streaming()
        .convertBodyTo(String.class)
        .choice()
            .when(simple("${header.CamelFileLength} &lt; 10" ))
                .wireTap("file:" + errorArchive)
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO,"File Size: ${header.CamelFileLength}, File is Empty or Zero Length!")
            .endChoice()
            .when(simple("${header.CamelFileLength} &gt; 10" ))
                .wireTap("file:" + fileArchive)
                .split(body().tokenize("\n"), new FleetAggregationStrategy()).streaming()
                .process(new EndpointParametersProcessor(decoderName))
                .end()
                .to(toStr)
            .endChoice()
        .end();

├── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  core
│   ├── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  enriched
│   ├── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  mt1
│   │   └── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  processed
│   ├── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  mt2
│   │   └── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  processed
│   ├── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  mt3
│   │   └── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  processed
│   └── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  tobeprocessed
├── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  dbase
├── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  fleet
│   └── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  core
│       ├── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  archive
│       └── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  error
│           ├── [-rw-r--r--    0]  GCMS_20190420-0815.csv
│           ├── [-rw-r--r--    0]  GCMS_20190420-0816.csv
│           ├── [-rw-r--r--    0]  GCMS_20190420-0817.csv
│           ├── [-rw-r--r-- 1.1M]  GCMS_20190420-0945.csv
│           ├── [-rw-r--r-- 1.1M]  GCMS_20190420-0953.csv
│           └── [-rw-r--r-- 1.1M]  GCMS_20190420-1001.csv
└── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  upload
```

Claus, I have tried the readlock limit, it has no impact here.

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    if (validateConfiguration()) {

        final String fromStr = String.format("%s://%s@%s:%s/%s?password=RAW(%s)&recursive=%s&stepwise=%s&useList=%s&passiveMode=%s&disconnect=%s"
                + "&move=.processed"
                + "&maxMessagesPerPoll=0"
                + "&eagerMaxMessagesPerPoll=false"
                + "&sortBy=file:modified"
                + "&sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=false"
                + "&delay=60000"
                + "&initialDelay=60000"
                + "&connectTimeout=15000"
                + "&localWorkDirectory=/tmp"
                + "&readLockMinLength=0"
                , transport, username, host, port, path, password, recursive, stepwise, useList, passiveMode, disconnect);

        // Format the To Endpoint from Parameter(s).
        final String toStr = String.format("%s", toEndpoint);
```

I have changed the route to look like the following, tried to simplify it. but it still doesn't work, in that it accepts all files even -0- zero length files which I do not want to process. 
I do believe it is how the choice.when simple statement is formed, something isn't quit right. I've tried many combinations all yielding same result.

```
            from(fromStr)
            .routeId("Zipped.Only")
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Message received ${file:name} for Only Zipped or Compressed files from host " + host)
            .unmarshal(zipFile)
            .split(body(Iterator.class))
            .streaming()
            .convertBodyTo(String.class)
            .wireTap("file:" + fileArchive)
            .choice()
             .when(simple("${header.CamelFileLength} > 0" ))
               .split(body().tokenize("\n"), new FleetAggregationStrategy()).streaming()
                 .process(new EndpointParametersProcessor(decoderName))
               .end()
               .to(toStr)
            .endChoice()
            .end();
```

yields, I only want to process or move to the tobeprocessed folder when the file has data or file.length != 0.  something is wrong with how the simple statement used??? I'll keep trying.

```
ge-digital/
├── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  core
│   ├── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  enriched
│   ├── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  mt1
│   │   └── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  processed
│   ├── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  mt2
│   │   └── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  processed
│   ├── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  mt3
│   │   └── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  processed
│   └── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  tobeprocessed
│       ├── [-rw-r--r--    0]  GCMS_20190420-0815.csv
│       ├── [-rw-r--r--    0]  GCMS_20190420-0816.csv
│       └── [-rw-r--r--    0]  GCMS_20190420-0817.csv
├── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  dbase
├── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  fleet
│   └── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  core
│       ├── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  archive
│       │   ├── [-rw-r--r--    0]  GCMS_20190420-0815.csv
│       │   ├── [-rw-r--r--    0]  GCMS_20190420-0816.csv
│       │   └── [-rw-r--r--    0]  GCMS_20190420-0817.csv
│       └── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  error
└── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  upload
```

The route basically working now EXCEPT the file length/size is wrong. it is the original file length NOT the split out files length.  How can I get around this?
before split - CamelFileLength: 598 and file.length: 598
after split - CamelFileLength: 598 and file.length: 598

```
        from(fromStr)
        .routeId("Zipped.Only")
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Message received ${file:name} for Only Zipped or Compressed files from host " + host)
        .unmarshal(zipFile)
        .split(body(Iterator.class))
        .streaming()
        .convertBodyTo(String.class)
        .wireTap("file:" + fileArchive)
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "before split - CamelFileLength: ${header.CamelFileLength} and file.length: ${file:length}")
        .split(body().tokenize("\n"), new FleetAggregationStrategy())  //.streaming()
        .process(new EndpointParametersProcessor(decoderName))
        .end()
        .choice()
        //.when(simple("${file:length} > 0"))
        .when(simple("${header.CamelFileLength} > '0'")) 
           .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "after split - CamelFileLength: ${header.CamelFileLength} and file.length: ${file:length}")
           .to(toStr)
        .otherwise()
           .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Message received ${file:name} is Empty or Null")
           .to("file:" + errorArchive)
        .end();
```

FINAL, ok, we finally have it working.  man, little things like this can set you back a bit.  for those interested and may help you.

I was using body.size, hmmm, wasn't giving the size of the body, I then used body.length and that worked.  many of the nice static methods i could not get working, I think I need to upgrade to new camel release. anyway, the problem is that the headers such as CamelFileLength and such carry the original file's length/size and not that which was split out by unmarshalling zipfile and splitting out all the files.  I was using headers until I realized the above, so, we used the body() for our predicate, and this worked, and use length

```
} else if (Boolean.parseBoolean(isCompressedOnly)) { //Only Zipped or Compressed

    ZipFileDataFormat zipFile = new ZipFileDataFormat();
    zipFile.setUsingIterator(true);

    from(fromStr)
    .routeId("Zipped.Only")
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Message received ${file:name} for Only Zipped or Compressed files from host " + host)
    .unmarshal(zipFile)
    .split(body(Iterator.class))
    .streaming()
    .convertBodyTo(String.class)
    .wireTap("file:" + fileArchive)
    .split(body().tokenize("\n"), new FleetAggregationStrategy()).streaming()
    .process(new EndpointParametersProcessor(decoderName))
    .end()
    .choice()
    .when(simple("${body.length} > '0'" ))
    .to(toStr)
    .end();
    // .when(simple("${file:length} == 0"))  
    // .when(simple("${header.CamelFileLength} == 0" )) 
    // .when(header("CamelFileLength").isEqualTo(0))
    // .when(body().isNull())
    // .when(body().isNotNull())
    // .when(header("CamelFileLength").isEqualTo(0))
    // .when(simple("${header.CamelFileLength} &lt; 10" ))
    // .when(simple("${header.CamelFileLength} &eq; 0" ))
    // .when(simple("${file:length} == null"))                  
} else {
```

Yields:

```
ge-digital/
├── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  core
│   ├── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  enriched
│   ├── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  error
│   │   └── [-rw-r--r--   47]  GCMS_2019-04-23_05-27-18.666.csv
│   ├── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  mt1
│   │   └── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  processed
│   ├── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  mt2
│   │   └── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  processed
│   ├── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  mt3
│   │   └── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  processed
│   │       ├── [-rw-r--r-- 2.9K]  GCMS_112-A-001_Gas_Turbine_2019-04-23_05-29-18.csv
│   │       ├── [-rw-r--r-- 2.1K]  GCMS_112-A-001_Gas_Turbine_cw_2019-04-23_05-29-18.csv
│   │       ├── [-rw-r--r--  911]  GCMS_112-A-001_Generator_2019-04-23_05-29-18.csv
│   │       ├── [-rw-r--r-- 2.8K]  GCMS_112-A-002_Gas_Turbine_2019-04-23_05-29-18.csv
│   │       ├── [-rw-r--r-- 2.1K]  GCMS_112-A-002_Gas_Turbine_cw_2019-04-23_05-29-18.csv
│   │       └── [-rw-r--r--  888]  GCMS_112-A-002_Generator_2019-04-23_05-29-18.csv
│   └── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  tobeprocessed
│       ├── [-rw-r--r-- 935K]  GCMS_2019-04-23_05-27-44.673.csv
│       ├── [-rw-r--r--    0]  GCMS_2019-04-23_05-27-44.673.csv.camelLock
│       ├── [-rw-r--r-- 941K]  GCMS_2019-04-23_05-28-07.013.csv
│       ├── [-rw-r--r-- 936K]  GCMS_2019-04-23_05-28-33.694.csv
│       ├── [-rw-r--r-- 939K]  GCMS_2019-04-23_05-29-02.300.csv
│       └── [-rw-r--r-- 946K]  GCMS_2019-04-23_05-29-28.928.csv
├── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  dbase
├── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  fleet
│   └── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  core
│       ├── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  archive
│       │   ├── [-rw-r--r-- 981K]  GCMS_20190319-0429.csv
│       │   ├── [-rw-r--r-- 977K]  GCMS_20190319-0437.csv
│       │   ├── [-rw-r--r-- 982K]  GCMS_20190319-0446.csv
│       │   ├── [-rw-r--r-- 977K]  GCMS_20190319-0454.csv
│       │   ├── [-rw-r--r-- 980K]  GCMS_20190319-0502.csv
│       │   ├── [-rw-r--r-- 988K]  GCMS_20190319-0511.csv
│       │   ├── [-rw-r--r--    0]  GCMS_20190420-0815.csv
│       │   ├── [-rw-r--r--    0]  GCMS_20190420-0816.csv
│       │   ├── [-rw-r--r--    0]  GCMS_20190420-0817.csv
│       │   ├── [-rw-r--r--    0]  GCMS_20190420-0818.csv
│       │   ├── [-rw-r--r--    0]  GCMS_20190420-0819.csv
│       │   ├── [-rw-r--r--    0]  GCMS_20190420-0820.csv
│       │   ├── [-rw-r--r--    0]  GCMS_20190420-0821.csv
│       │   ├── [-rw-r--r--    0]  GCMS_20190420-0822.csv
│       │   ├── [-rw-r--r--    0]  GCMS_20190420-0823.csv
│       │   ├── [-rw-r--r--    0]  GCMS_20190420-0824.csv
│       │   ├── [-rw-r--r--    0]  GCMS_20190420-0825.csv
│       │   ├── [-rw-r--r--  15K]  GCMS_20190420-0826.csv
│       │   ├── [-rw-r--r--    0]  GCMS_20190420-0827.csv
│       │   ├── [-rw-r--r--    0]  GCMS_20190420-0828.csv
│       │   └── [-rw-r--r--    0]  GCMS_20190420-0829.csv
│       └── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  error
└── [drwxr-xr-x 4.0K]  upload
```

Comment: Can you better describe what is not working? Have you seen that there is a readLockMinLength option on the file component you need to set to 0 to allow to pickup empty files.

Comment: thanks Claus! I will try the readLockMinLength option, however, I am trying to simply discard zero length files, and process only files with content.  Claus, where can I find the methods docs for header language, I don't know if I can use or what param it takes, such as header().isEqualTo("A") where can I find the methods desc like isEqualTo() ?  thanks

Comment: The situation is that the files that traverse this route are compressed files, the sftp consumer will pick up the zip file, decompress it, then find the files, sometimes these files are zero -0- length

Comment: ok, I know what is going on. it is the placement of the choice.when block, looking ahead at the camel file length shows the file size still as that of the zipped file, not as the files split from zip file. .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "CamelFileLength: ${header.CamelFileLength} and file.length: ${file:length}") shows CamelFileLength: 598 and file.length: 598 at this juncture.

Comment: Claus, thank you, Now the real problem shows up.  it appears that the file length of the original file, the zipped compressed file is kept throughout the route travel.  is there a way to capture the file size here?  please see new code post.

Comment: Claus, thank you. got it working. this one was interesting. well, they're all interesting. one day.